# Swift Classes in One File

Tags: swift, class

I know in python it is good practice to have a **models.py** and put all of an application's model classes in there. Does the same apply to swift or is it better to have a separate file for each model class?

Thanks!

Comment: This is up to you. The language does not make it a requirement one way or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple recommends to have separate files for each model class however it's possible to use the "Python style"

Comment: I expect that's probably true, but can you provide a link to Apple's recommendation?

Comment: Just look at the sample code in the developer library 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your project is average..I would put each of your models in a separate file. Sometimes you end up with some small files, but I would rather go through that then some massive file where I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single correct answer to this question, but Swift's system of controlling access suggests that it is not the best practice.

Properties and methods marked `private` are only visible within the same source file. If you put all of your model classes into a single file, they will all have access to each others' `private` methods and properties, which defeats the whole purpose of marking something `private`.