# Swift classes and file names

Tags: swift

In several cocoapods projects I found that it is possible to create a one file, e.g., `ViewController.swift` that contains ***ALL*** classes of the project. I can't find in the manual is this feature usual for swift? Is it a good practice? Pros and Cons of this huge file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713566/swift-classes-in-one-file

Comment: Yes, it is allowed. Pros and cons depend on what you are doing. Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: pros/cons figure out that, if you like searching anything in big file it is up to you. There is no modern language with something like that as a "feature"

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Is there any description in Apple docs?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommend to put many classes into one file.

You should put a single class in a single file with the same name:

- Easier to find the class and easier to read.
- It would be easier to maintain. Many people edit one big file will result in conflicts.
- Better to work with a version controller.
- and many other pros...

It's better to keep a file / a class small using single responsibility principle.